# Create a custom input element

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I'm trying to create a custom component that extends the `HTMLInputElement` component, but nothing renders.

```js
class myInput extends HTMLInputElement {};

customElements.define('my-input', myInput, {
  extends: 'input'
});
```

```html
<my-input type="text"></my-input>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you are expecting is not happening because that's not the correct way to extend an already built-in element.

As MDN documentation states, you need to keep the built-in tag in your DOM and affect it a [`is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#Customized_built-in_element) attribute.

Look at the snippet below by focusing on the *spot input*.

```js
class spotInput extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    
    this.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('Focus on spotinput');
    });
  }
};

customElements.define('spot-input', spotInput, {
  extends: 'input',
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="simple input">
<input is="spot-input" type="text" placeholder="spot input">
```

But I am guessing that you want to be allowed to use a `<spot-input>` tag. You can do that by attaching [a shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM),  creating [an autonomous element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#Autonomous_custom_element) and append it a `<input>`.

```js
class spotInput extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    
    // Attaches a shadow root to your custom element.
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    
    // Defines the "real" input element.
    let inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.setAttribute('type', this.getAttribute('type'));
    
    inputElement.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('focus on spot input');
    });
    
    // Appends the input into the shadow root.
    shadowRoot.appendChild(inputElement);
  }
};

customElements.define('spot-input', spotInput);
```

```html
<input type="number">
<spot-input type="number"></spot-input>
```

Then, if you check the DOM tree, you should have:

```html
<input type="number">

<spot-input type="number">
    #shadow-root (open)
        <input type="number">
</spot-input>
```

Comment: Worth noting, Safari does not support the `is="..."` and does not ever plan to.

Comment: Nice Answer!  Particularly the addition of the directions to use the Custom Autonomous Element for the correct implementation, since, as run_the_race mentions, the Custom Built-in Elements are not supported in Safari on the Mac.  

You do not,, though, necessarily have to create a shadow dom, unless it's something you want to keep  private and secure.  Also, the creation of the markup should go into a connectedCallback() method.